# tkinter entry textvariable not displaying in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

There have been similar questions asked, but none reflect the behavior I am seeing. I have a GUI that was working perfectly in Python 2.7. I recently updated to 3.5.2, and altered my tkinter imports appropriately, so it runs. However, none of the textvariable attributes of my Entry widgets are displaying. The values are stored properly, just not displaying. Here is a minimal example:

```
import tkinter as tk
class App:
    def __init__(self,window):
        self.root = window
        self.var = tk.DoubleVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root,textvariable=self.var)
        self.var.set(1.3)
        self.entry.pack()
main = tk.Tk()
App(main)
main.mainloop()
```

I have also tried putting the `self.var.set(1.3)` line immediately after the initialization, but it doesn't work. Running this gives me an empty entry widget.

I am running Python 3.5.2 in Enthought Canopy, using iPython 5.3.0

Comment: This code works fine for me with python 3.5.2. Perhaps this is a bug in iPython or Canopy.

Comment: Dang, you're right. I just ran it in the command prompt, and it's fine. Then ran iPython from command prompt, then ran from iPython, and it's fine. Somehow it's a Canopy problem!

Comment: Is Canopy tk-based? If so, it might be doing to something to aggressively clean up abandoned widgets, which is generally helpful for interactive sessions trying to do Tk stuff? I remember one of the third-party IDEs did this. If so, just storing that `App(main)` in a variable until at least after `main.mainloop()` finishes might solve it. (And that’s probably a good idea anyway.)

Comment: I originally had `App(main)` in a variable: `app = App(main)`. It doesn't make a difference either way. I did find a preference to change the PyLab interactive backend, which was auto-selected. You are correct! Specifying something other than Tk allows it to run properly. Thanks! If you make that an answer, I can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As alluded to in the comments, this turned out to be a Canopy problem. Specifically, when it uses tk for the Pylab backend (option in Preferences/Python). Switching it from tk eliminated the problem.